# Illegal Start of Expression, trying to print

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting several errors here, a ";" and ")" expected error, an "illegal start of expression error and a "not a statement error."

These two lines are the culprits.

```
System.out.println("Rectangle alpha has a width of "+alpha.width+", a height of "+alpha.height+" a perimeter of "alpha.getPerimeter()+" and an area of "+alpha.getArea()+".");
System.out.println("Rectangle beta has a width of "+beta.width+", a height of "+beta.height+" a perimeter of "beta.getPerimeter()+" and an area of "+beta.getArea()+".");
```

Unfortunately this is one of those times where I don't even know what I don't know to look for  what I need to understand/fix this. I actually wanted to use a method to print these two, but I got 'not a statement errors' when I decided to instead do the above and get many more errors...

Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for like 2 hours...not understanding what was wrong...The code itself took 10% of the time :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `+` in between your string and `alpha.getPerimeter()`/`beta.getPerimeter()`.

```
System.out.println("Rectangle alpha has a width of "+alpha.width+", a height of "+alpha.height+" a perimeter of "+alpha.getPerimeter()+" and an area of "+alpha.getArea()+".");
System.out.println("Rectangle beta has a width of "+beta.width+", a height of "+beta.height+" a perimeter of "+beta.getPerimeter()+" and an area of "+beta.getArea()+".");
```

I always put a space on both sides of operators. This issue confirmed why I do that - you would have definitely noticed the missing `+` had you done this.

Comment: Good catch, but your final statement seems a bit of a leap.

Comment: Using a StringBuilder instead of concatenating String objects (which is not generally recommended) would also have solved this problem.